# Model not learning in Cat-Dog Image classification using Keras

Tags: cnn, image-classification, training, model-selection

```
def CNN(cat,dog,test):

    cat=np.reshape(cat,(cat.shape[0],64,64,3))
    dog=np.reshape(dog,(dog.shape[0],64,64,3))
    xtrain=np.concatenate((cat,dog),0)
    ytrain=np.asarray([1 if i<len(cat) else 0 for i in range(len(cat)+len(dog))])
    xtest=np.reshape(test,(test.shape[0],64,64,3))

    indices=np.arange(xtrain.shape[0])
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    xtrain=xtrain[indices]
    ytrain=ytrain[indices]



    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation="sigmoid",input_shape=(64,64,3)))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    #model.add(BatchNormalization())
    #model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    #model.add(BatchNormalization())
    #model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1)
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())

    #print(ytrain)
    #print(xtrain[0].mean())

    model.fit(xtrain,ytrain, batch_size=32, epochs=10, shuffle=1)

    #ynew=model.

    outcomes=model.predict(xtest)
    ytest=[np.argmax(i) for i in outcomes] #change to round-off

    return (outcomes,ytest)
```

After training, I am getting accuracy of around 55-59 % but it is expected to go above 90% easily.

I think I have made a very silly error with the model or with the data formatting. Can you please help me point the mistake.

[image: Model summary]

[image: Training epochs result]

Comment: Random hints: add two additional conv layers. Don't use sigmoid activation on the input layer. Use validation split in the fit method. The depth in the conv layers should grow.

Comment: Thankyou @MichaelM . That was helpful as the model is operating properly now. It seems that the validation split was important.

Comment: Glad to hear, thanks for the feedback.